UsernameNotOccupiedError in python Telethon when a group is deleted
I am using telethon 1.36.0 python library to listen for new telegram messages of specific groups.
This is my relevant code:
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel_names))
async def handler(event):
    try:
        sender = await event.get_sender()
        message = event.message
        print(message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

where channel_names is a list of telegram groups usernames I joined to.
If a group is deleted during script execution (while I listen for new messages) and another one of the groups I listen for posts a message, the exception is never triggered and my script crashes due to the following error:
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.UsernameNotOccupiedError: The username is not in use by anyone else yet (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    raise ValueError('No user has "{}" as username'
ValueError: No user has "my_channel_username" as username

Is there a way to prevent that?
